# R - Identifying where two rasters have different values and plotting these differences

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I'm new to GIS processing in R. I have two rasters within the same area, and I need to calculate where their values are different and plot those differences. **How can I do this?** All of the data mentioned in this question [can be found and downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p5zLTgAfs7sx2KxjMBe-fWDCkCoJkruS?usp=sharing).

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#Read packages
library(sf)
library(raster)

#Read the data
cdl_2016 <- raster('CDL_2016_clip_20220329135051_1368678123.tif')
cdl_2019 <- raster('CDL_2019_clip_20220329135051_1368678123.tif')
wcw <- st_read("Wildcat_Creek_Watershed.shp")

#Change projection of wcw to match the rasters
wcw <- st_transform(wcw, crs(cdl_2016))

#Plot data to examine what we are working with
plot(cdl_2016)
plot(cdl_2019)

#Clip data to shapefile
wcw_2016 <- crop(cdl_2016, wcw)
wcw_2016 <- mask(wcw_2016, mask = wcw)
plot(wcw_2016)

wcw_2019 <- crop(cdl_2019, wcw)
wcw_2019 <- mask(wcw_2019, mask = wcw)
plot(wcw_2019)

#Examine the unique raster values. A legend is available at: https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/
unique(wcw_2016)
unique(wcw_2019)
```

I thought that finding the differences between the rasters would work, but the output is a raster with negative numbers. *I only need to find and plot where they are different from one another.*

```
dif_rast = wcw_2019 - wcw_2016
plot(dif_rast)
freq(dif_rast)
```

The output from the freq(dif_raster):

```
     value  count
  [1,]  -212      1
  [2,]  -194      2
  [3,]  -191      1
  [4,]  -189     19
  [5,]  -185     16
  [6,]  -175    183
  [7,]  -172     27
  [8,]  -171    286
  [9,]  -166      2
 [10,]  -159      1
 [11,]  -158      5
 [12,]  -154      3
 [13,]  -153      2
 [14,]  -152     28
 [15,]  -150      3
 [16,]  -149     12
 [17,]  -148      1
 [18,]  -141      1
 [19,]  -140    178
 [20,]  -139    917
 [21,]  -137      3
 [22,]  -136     73
 [23,]  -130      1
 [24,]  -126      5
 [25,]  -121     13
 [26,]  -120    189
 [27,]  -118      7
 [28,]  -117     21
 [29,]  -116    163
 [30,]  -115     23
 [31,]  -106      2
 [32,]  -105     13
 [33,]  -104     19
 [34,]   -99      2
 [35,]   -98      8
 [36,]   -97     18
 [37,]   -95      2
 [38,]   -90      1
 [39,]   -86      1
 [40,]   -85     22
 [41,]   -84    112
 [42,]   -79      1
 [43,]   -74     12
 [44,]   -73      2
 [45,]   -70      1
 [46,]   -69     35
 [47,]   -68     15
 [48,]   -67      2
 [49,]   -65     54
 [50,]   -64      1
 [51,]   -61      2
 [52,]   -60     29
 [53,]   -59      1
 [54,]   -58      1
 [55,]   -57     10
 [56,]   -56     23
 [57,]   -55   1529
 [58,]   -54    747
 [59,]   -53    435
 [60,]   -52     59
 [61,]   -50      1
 [62,]   -49    781
 [63,]   -47      1
 [64,]   -45     54
 [65,]   -37     14
 [66,]   -36     13
 [67,]   -35   1666
 [68,]   -34      2
 [69,]   -33     17
 [70,]   -32     14
 [71,]   -31    140
 [72,]   -30      6
 [73,]   -27     10
 [74,]   -25      6
 [75,]   -24      4
 [76,]   -23     67
 [77,]   -21      1
 [78,]   -20    426
 [79,]   -19    265
 [80,]   -18     66
 [81,]   -17      6
 [82,]   -14     45
 [83,]   -13      1
 [84,]   -12     28
 [85,]   -11      4
 [86,]   -10     27
 [87,]    -9     14
 [88,]    -8     24
 [89,]    -7      2
 [90,]    -4   2606
 [91,]    -3    381
 [92,]    -2     42
 [93,]    -1   1031
 [94,]     0 101236
 [95,]     1   1381
 [96,]     2     90
 [97,]     3     51
 [98,]     4   1849
 [99,]     5     18
[100,]     7      1
[101,]     8      7
[102,]    10      3
[103,]    11      2
[104,]    12     45
[105,]    13      4
[106,]    14      6
[107,]    18      3
[108,]    19    273
[109,]    20    716
[110,]    21     70
[111,]    22     10
[112,]    23     12
[113,]    24      1
[114,]    25      4
[115,]    29      3
[116,]    30     88
[117,]    31     39
[118,]    32     46
[119,]    33      6
[120,]    34      1
[121,]    35    729
[122,]    36      4
[123,]    37     21
[124,]    45     59
[125,]    48      2
[126,]    49    115
[127,]    50     12
[128,]    52      1
[129,]    53      3
[130,]    54    126
[131,]    55   1170
[132,]    56    209
[133,]    57     51
[134,]    60     66
[135,]    61      2
[136,]    62      6
[137,]    63      1
[138,]    65    124
[139,]    69      2
[140,]    70     17
[141,]    79      1
[142,]    80      1
[143,]    84      4
[144,]    85      8
[145,]    86      2
[146,]    87      5
[147,]    88      1
[148,]    93      1
[149,]    94      1
[150,]    95      1
[151,]    96      6
[152,]    97      1
[153,]    98      2
[154,]    99      2
[155,]   104     10
[156,]   105     23
[157,]   106      1
[158,]   115      8
[159,]   116     57
[160,]   117     35
[161,]   118     21
[162,]   119      5
[163,]   120     14
[164,]   121      6
[165,]   122     26
[166,]   123      8
[167,]   136     20
[168,]   137      2
[169,]   139    204
[170,]   140     28
[171,]   152      1
[172,]   159      1
[173,]   171     33
[174,]   172     18
[175,]   175     17
[176,]   185      1
[177,]   189      1
[178,]   231      2
[179,]    NA 238680
```

Comment: You can simply calculate the difference (subtract the rasters) and plot the resulted raster (set 0s to null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to subtract the rasters and set the non-zero values to a value different than zero. Upon plotting, the values corresponding to 1 indicated that the areas had changed over the years, whereas areas corresponding to 0 indicated no change.

```
dif <- wcw_2019 - wcw_2016

dif[dif != 0] <- 1
plot(dif)
```